# checking Code Quotation structure during compile time

Tags: reflection, f#

can I define a quotation expression paramter such that not only the resulting type of the expression is compile time checked 
but also the call site expression.

lets see an example:

```
type A = {
    a : int
}

type Checker () =
     static member Check(e : Expr<int>) : ResultType = ...
```

The following obviously type check

```
let a = { a = 1 }
Checker.Check <@ a.a @>
```

Resulting in an actual Expression similar to `PropertyGet( ..., PropertyGet (....), a)`.

And now some other way

```
let getInt (a:A) : int = a.a
```

The following also compiles

```
Checker.Check <@ getInt a @>
```

However how can I prevent that second example compiles and only allow for `PropertyGet`s? (just as an example).
I know I can check the structure of the expression at run time - but I like to have an compile time check.

Comment: You can't. If this is a critical requirement, I suggest using a library of combinators instead of quotations.

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: You can make your combinators (or, rather, the data type they produce) not allow creating invalid data. You know, "make invalid data irrepresentable" and all that.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if combinators help that much. I could for example define `static member Check (c:SomeCombinator<A->int>) = ...` but would that really help if I instatiate it like that? `Checker.Check (SomeCombinator (fun a -> 99))`. Granted it is better than simply checking for the resulting type but only slightly so

Answer (score 1):

As Fyodor said in a comment, there is no way to ensure that quotations are only of a certain shape at compile-time. This is quite unfortunate, but all quotation-based (or expression-tree based) libraries suffer from this (most notably LINQ) and if your requirement is "only property-getters" then I suppose you can probably just leave this as a runtime check.

If I really wanted to guarantee this, I would probably try to use the [F# Compiler Service](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service), which lets you get [typed expression tree](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/typedtree.html). You could then walk over the tree and find all quotations in the project and report the errors (it could be done in some extensible way as a linter plugin, which others might benefit from too).

If you went in the DSL direction, then you could write, say, `a |> get "foo" |> get "bar"` (using pipe), or `a?foo?bar` (using the `?` operator), but then you lose checking on the names, which seems to be worse than not being able to check the correct shape of a quotation.

Comment: the untyped variant is definitly no way to go ;-) I am however not sure how the compiler services and the typed expression tree would help. At least if we are talking in the context of normal workflow and not a 2-pass compilation. Can you maybe sketch out how you would envision that?

Comment: @robkuz You'd definitely need something like a two-pass compilation. But you could do this as an integration in FSharpLint (https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint) and have it as a VS plugin, which would make the experience nicer.